# iOS 11 & iPhone X: UINavigationBar's toolbar spacing incorrect when embedded in UITabBarController

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ios11, iphone-x

I am experiencing an annoying problem testing the newest iOS 11 on the iPhone X simulator.

I have an `UITabBarController` and inside each tab there is a `UINavigationController`, each `UINavigationBar` has defined also a bottom toolBar (`setToolbarHidden:`), and by default they show up at the bottom, just over the tabBar.

It has been working fine so far and seems to work fine also in the upcomming iPhone 8 and 8 Plus models, but on the iPhone X there is a gap between the toolBar and the tabBar. My guess is that the toolBar doesn't realize that is displayed inside a tabBar and then leaves the accommodating space at the bottom.

I guess the only way to fix it would be using a custom toolbar and display/animate it myself instead of using the defaults `UINavigationBar`, but I would like to hear other options :)

- This is how it looks on iPhone 8.
- And here is the problem on iPhone X.

[image] [image]

Comment: Did you find any solution for this problem? I am experiencing similar issue.

Comment: @AtWork Nope, unfortunately nothing yet... Hopefully Apple will fix it in upcoming releases.

Comment: The lower space is normal as iOS tries to extend tabbar height to have space for new home line. But I have the same problem with upper space.

Comment: @Mousavian Yes, the lower space makes sense in iPhone X for home line but its weird why the toolbar is not aligned with tabbar.

Comment: @AtWork Exactly, I just wanted to point out that both spaces are similar, meaning that the origin of the problem is the toolbar not being aware that there is a tabbar under...

Comment: Here is, what I found: Due to a bug (in iOS and/or XCode), the tabbar is not aligned correctly to the bottom. It has to be higher so that the gab on top disappears. If one, for instance adds a tabbar to a regular UIViewController, you can see exactly this (higer tabbar, gap under tabbar) and for some reason, this doesn't happen to a UITabbarController. So it's quite obvious that this is another Apple bug. Apple needs to fix this as all workarounds will cause problems and headaches in future versions. This is always the same, all the years, not really tested, not really thought through.

Comment: I am facing the same issue that above the custom tabbar, there is gap and it is non touchable area.

Comment: I worked on this for about 2 hours. I think you're screwed until Apple fixes the issue. I think what you're saying is right, about the toolbar not being aware it's in a tab bar. However, you have almost no control over the nav controller private toolbar.

I thought there might be something with setting "insetsLayoutMarginsFromSafeArea = false", but no dice.

Comment: I am experiencing an issue which may be related to this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46701391/iphone-x-safe-area-appears-to-be-below-opaque-toolbar

Comment: I just discovered a Tip box in Apple's iOS HIG at the bottom of both the [Toolbars](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/bars/toolbars/) page and Tab Bars page. The last sentence reads, "_Tab bars and toolbars never appear together in the same view._" Given that this problem exists because it is against their design guidelines I fear Apple may not quickly address it. Rather than hoping that Apple releases a fix for the iPhone X at launch, I'm trying to remove all Toolbars from my Tab Bar scenes.

Comment: This appears to be fixed in iOS 11.2, using the simulator from Xcode 9.2 beta (9C32c).

Comment: @greg Wow, that is amazing. Please write down an answer with this and maybe add a screenshot and I will gladly mark it as the correct one. Thanks :)

Comment: It appears to be back again in iOS 13 (betas) and Xcode 11 (betas). I sure hope this is an Apple bug. I’ll file a bug report.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I filed this as radr://problem/34421298, which was closed as a duplicate of radr://problem/34462371. However, in the latest beta of Xcode 9.2 (9C32c) with iOS 11.2, this seems to be fixed. Here's an example of my app running in the simulator of each device, with no changes in between.

[image: Navbar toolbar under iOS 11.1 and 11.2]

This isn't really a *solution* to your problem, other than that some patience may solve it without needing to resort to UI trickery. My assumption is that iOS 11.2 will be out before the end of the year, since it's needed to support HomePod.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't consider rotations you can try to manipulate the layer of the toolbar as a very hacky yet fast workaround.

```
class FixNavigationController: UINavigationController
{
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        updateTollbarPosition()
    }

    func updateTollbarPosition() {
        guard let tabbarFrame = tabBarController?.tabBar.frame else {
            return
        }
        let gapHeight = tabbarFrame.origin.y-toolbar.frame.origin.y-toolbar.frame.size.height

        var
        frame = toolbar.layer.frame
        frame.origin.y += gapHeight

        toolbar.layer.frame = frame
    }    
}
```

Unfortunately, rotation animation doesn't look good when it comes to this approach. In this case, adding the custom toolbar instead of the standard one will be a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

I have found only one workaround: add toolbar directly to the view controller

[image]

Comment: Thank you, but as I said in the original question: "I guess the only way to fix it would be using a custom toolbar and display/animate it myself instead of using the defaults UINavigationBar, but I would like to hear other options :)"

Answer (score 1):

iOS 11.1 and iPhone X are released and this bug/feature isn't fixed yet. So I implemented this workaround. This code works in iOS 9.0+.

Just set this class in your storyboard as navigation controller's class. It will use custom toolbar in iPhone X with correct layout constraints, and falls back to native one in other devices. The custom toolbar is added to navigation controller's view instead of your view controller, to make transitions smoother.

- **Important Note:** You have to call `updateItems(animated:)` manually after setting `toolbarItems` of your view controller to update interface. If you set `toolbarItems` property of navigation controller, you can ignore this step.

It simulates all native toolbar behavior (including changing toolbar height in portrait/landscape modes), except push/pop animations.

```
import UIKit

class FixNavigationController: UINavigationController {

    private weak var alterToolbarHeightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint?

    private var _alterToolbar: UIToolbar?

    private func initAlretToolbar() {
        _alterToolbar = UIToolbar()
        _alterToolbar!.isTranslucent = true
        _alterToolbar!.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(_alterToolbar!)
        if view.traitCollection.verticalSizeClass == .compact {
            alterToolbarHeightConstraint = _alterToolbar!.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 32.0)
        } else {
            alterToolbarHeightConstraint = _alterToolbar!.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 44.0)
        }
        let bottomAnchor: NSLayoutConstraint
        if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
            bottomAnchor = _alterToolbar!.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor)
        } else {
            bottomAnchor = _alterToolbar!.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomLayoutGuide.topAnchor)
        }
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            _alterToolbar!.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
            _alterToolbar!.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
            bottomAnchor,
            alterToolbarHeightConstraint!
            ])
        self.view.updateFocusIfNeeded()
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }

    private var alterToolbarInSuper: UIToolbar? {
        var superNavigationController = self.navigationController as? FixNavigationController
        while superNavigationController != nil {
            if superNavigationController?._alterToolbar != nil {
                return superNavigationController?._alterToolbar
            }
            superNavigationController = superNavigationController?.navigationController as? FixNavigationController
        }
        return nil
    }

    private var alterToolbar: UIToolbar! {
        get {
            if let t = alterToolbarInSuper {
                return t
            }
            if _alterToolbar == nil {
                initAlretToolbar()
            }
            return _alterToolbar
        }
    }

    // This is the logic to determine should use custom toolbar or fallback to native one
    private var shouldUseAlterToolbar: Bool {
        // return true if height is iPhone X's one
        return UIScreen.main.nativeBounds.height == 2436
    }

    /// Manually call it after setting toolbar items in child view controllers
    func updateItems(animated: Bool = false) {
        if shouldUseAlterToolbar {
            (_alterToolbar ?? alterToolbarInSuper)?.setItems(viewControllers.last?.toolbarItems ?? toolbarItems, animated: animated)
        }
    }

    override var isToolbarHidden: Bool {
        get {
            if shouldUseAlterToolbar {
                return _alterToolbar == nil && alterToolbarInSuper == nil
            } else {
                return super.isToolbarHidden
            }
        }
        set {
            if shouldUseAlterToolbar {
                if newValue {
                    super.isToolbarHidden = newValue
                    _alterToolbar?.removeFromSuperview()
                    _alterToolbar = nil
                    self.view.updateFocusIfNeeded()
                    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
                    // TODO: Animation when push/pop
                    alterToolbarHeightConstraint = nil
                    var superNavigationController = self.navigationController as? FixNavigationController
                    while let superNC = superNavigationController {
                        if superNC._alterToolbar != nil {
                            superNC._alterToolbar?.removeFromSuperview()
                            superNC._alterToolbar = nil
                            superNC.view.updateFocusIfNeeded()
                            superNC.view.layoutIfNeeded()
                        }
                        superNavigationController = superNC.navigationController as? FixNavigationController
                    }
                } else {
                    alterToolbar.setItems(viewControllers.last?.toolbarItems ?? toolbarItems, animated: false)
                }
            } else {
                super.isToolbarHidden = newValue
            }
        }
    }

    override func setToolbarItems(_ toolbarItems: [UIBarButtonItem]?, animated: Bool) {
        super.setToolbarItems(toolbarItems, animated: animated)
        updateItems(animated: animated)
    }

    override var toolbarItems: [UIBarButtonItem]? {
        get {
            return super.toolbarItems
        }
        set {
            super.toolbarItems = newValue
            updateItems()
        }
    }

    override func traitCollectionDidChange(_ previousTraitCollection: UITraitCollection?) {
        guard let _alterToolbar = _alterToolbar else {
            return
        }
        self.alterToolbarHeightConstraint?.isActive = false
        let height: CGFloat = (view.traitCollection.verticalSizeClass == .compact) ? 32.0 : 44.0
        let alterToolbarHeightConstraint = _alterToolbar.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: height)
        alterToolbarHeightConstraint.isActive = true
        self.alterToolbarHeightConstraint = alterToolbarHeightConstraint
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Apple still has not yet fixed this bug in iOS 11.2. Derived from Mousavian's solution, here is a simpler approach that I took.

I took this approach because I have just one UITableViewController where this bug happens. So in my case, I just added the following code listed below to my ViewController (which is UITableViewController) where this bug happens.

Advantages are:

- This fix just takes over in case of an iPhone X. No side effects to expect on other devices
- Works with any transition
- Works regardless of other parent/child controllers having Toolbars or not
- Simple

And here is the code:

1.Add **startFixIPhoneXToolbarBug** to your **viewWillAppear** like this:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool)
{
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    startFixIPhoneXToolbarBug()
}
```

2.Add **endFixIPhoneXToolbarBug** to your **viewWillDisappear** like this:

```
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool)
{
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

    endFixIPhoneXToolbarBug()
}
```

3.Implement **start/endFixIPhoneXToolbarBug** in your **viewController** like this:

```
private var alterToolbarHeightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint? = nil
private var alterToolbar: UIToolbar? = nil

func startFixIPhoneXToolbarBug()
{
    // Check if we are running on an iPhone X
    if UIScreen.main.nativeBounds.height != 2436
    {
        return  // No
    }
    // See if we have a Toolbar
    if let tb:UIToolbar = self.navigationController?.toolbar
    {
        // See if we already added our own
        if alterToolbar == nil
        {
            // Should always be the case
            if let tbView = tb.superview
            {
                // Create a new Toolbar and apply correct constraints
                alterToolbar = UIToolbar()
                alterToolbar!.isTranslucent = true
                alterToolbar!.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
                tb.isHidden = true
                tbView.addSubview(alterToolbar!)
                if tbView.traitCollection.verticalSizeClass == .compact
                {
                    alterToolbarHeightConstraint = alterToolbar!.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 32.0)
                }
                else
                {
                    alterToolbarHeightConstraint = alterToolbar!.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 44.0)
                }
                let bottomAnchor: NSLayoutConstraint
                if #available(iOS 11.0, *)
                {
                    bottomAnchor = alterToolbar!.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: tbView.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor)
                }
                else
                {
                    bottomAnchor = alterToolbar!.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomLayoutGuide.topAnchor)
                }
                NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
                    alterToolbar!.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: tbView.leadingAnchor),
                    alterToolbar!.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: tbView.trailingAnchor),
                    bottomAnchor,
                    alterToolbarHeightConstraint!
                    ])
                tbView.updateFocusIfNeeded()
                tbView.layoutIfNeeded()
            }
        }
        // Add the original items to the new toolbox
        alterToolbar!.setItems(tb.items, animated: false)
    }
}

func endFixIPhoneXToolbarBug()
{
    if alterToolbar != nil
    {
        alterToolbar!.removeFromSuperview()
        alterToolbar = nil
        alterToolbarHeightConstraint = nil

        if let tb:UIToolbar = self.navigationController?.toolbar
        {
            tb.isHidden = false
        }
    }
}
```