# iPhone X Safe Area Appears to be below Opaque Toolbar

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch, autolayout, iphone-x

I can't properly constrain a view on the iPhone X to be above the bottom opaque toolbar.

You can see here that the view constrained to the bottom of the Safe area is obscured by the toolbar:

[image: iPhone X screenshot]

While for other iPhone models and sizes the view is correctly displayed above the toolbar:

[image: iPhone SE storyboard screenshot]

Here are the constraints I've added:

[image: Constraints]

Could someone kindly explain me what should I do?

Comment: see this may be helps you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46441988/autoresizing-for-iphone-x/46442867#46442867

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've solved the issue by selecting "Extend edges under Opaque Bars" for the UIViewController in question:

With option enabled:
[image: IB extend edges ticked]

With option disabled:
[image: IB extend edges unticked]

The other option is to use a translucent toolbar as @Silmaril has mentioned in another answer to the question.

Comment: Are you sure you did not changed your toolbar style to translucent as well?Because I still can reproduce your bug when toolbar is not translucent. Which means enabling `Extend edges under Opaque Bars` is not a fix

Answer (score 3):

This is definitely iOS bug.

Try use translucent toolbar because bug is not reproducible when toolbar is translucent.

Other option is to add toolbar [directly on view controller](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46802241/2083655)

Comment: Safe area's top is a top of the screen, so the label will be aligned below the status bar. However I need the label to be at the bottom.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I mixed up safe area and layout guide in my head. Btw I just I don't see toolbar on your screenshots. I just tried created test project from `Single View App` template. And I don't have your issue on iPhone X. What are black areas on your screenshots? I don't have them as well

Comment: looks like you used simulated metrics. In this case this just bug of Interface Builder. Try running your app on iPhone X simulator when real toolbar is presented. If there is no other bug there (this time bug in iOS) you should not encounter this issue

Comment: Of course the problem is present on the simulator. Black area is a simulated opaque toolbars, it is stated in the description. Just add any button to the bottom toolbar using the toolbarItems property of the UIViewController and you will see that this toolbar will partially cover the view exactly like it is shown in the IB.

Comment: `toolbarItems` property don't add toolbar view to view controller. Quote from documentation `This property contains an array of UIBarButtonItem objects and works in conjunction with a UINavigationController object.` Are you using navigation controller?

Comment: Oh, yes, sorry for that, I am indeed adding them to the navigation controller.

Comment: See my answer, somehow this helped me with an issue.

Answer (score -2):

use size to fit content ⌘ (+) = 
[image]